# Pinescript code not generating tradingview strategy results

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

The code is below.

```
//@version=4
strategy("52 Weeks High with Trailing Stop", overlay=true)

// Define input variables
trailStopPercent = input(1.0, "Trailing Stop Percentage")

// Calculate the 52-week high
high52Weeks = highest(high, 252)

// Define entry conditions
enterLong = close \> high52Weeks

// Define exit conditions
exitLong = close \< low\[1\] \* (1 - trailStopPercent / 100)

// Calculate position size based on account capital
accountCapital = strategy.equity
positionSize = accountCapital \* 0.01 // 1% of account capital

// Execute long trade
if enterLong and strategy.position_size == 0
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty = positionSize)

// Exit long trade
if exitLong
strategy.close("Long")

// Plotting 52-week high
plot(high52Weeks, "52 Weeks High", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Run the code, expecting results in the strategy, displayed in the performance window in trading view but unfortunately did not return any results. It only displayed the overly on the chart but not the actual strategy results and performance.

Answer (score 0):

`enterLong = close > high52Weeks` can never be `true`. `highest()` will return the highest price within the given period. Price cannot close higher than the "*highest*".

Also, the way you are getting the 52-week high does not make any sense to me. Why are you using 252 as your length?

Lastly, your position size calculation is also wrong. If you want to use a price value in `qty`, you should add `default_qty_type=strategy.cash` to your `strategy()` call.

Comment: Thanks, This was my original code, below


strategy("52 Weeks High with Trailing Stop", overlay=true)

trailStopPercent = input(1.0, "Trailing Stop Percentage")

// Calculate the 52-week high
high52Weeks = highest(high, 52)

// Define entry conditions
enterLong = close > high52Weeks

// Define exit conditions
exitLong = close < low[1] * (1 - trailStopPercent / 100)

if enterLong
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if exitLong
    strategy.close("Long")

// Plotting 52-week high
plot(high52Weeks, "52 Weeks High", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)